# pyspark - select new column with hardcoded value

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to query a dataframe and add a column with a set value but I'm not sure how to get it to work.  I know how it works in SQL but I could use help converting it to pyspark.

PL/SQL Example:
SELECT 1 AS column1
,2 AS column2
FROM dual;

[image]

pyspark:
empDF.select("name", col("").alias("nullColumn")).display()

[image]

Comment: `lit("1").alias("colName")`

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the `withColumn()` function. Can be used in conjunction with `lit()`
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html

A new column can be added to an existing dataframe using this option.

Sample Example:

```py
df.withColumn("Country", lit("USA")).show()
df.withColumn("Country", lit("USA")) \
  .withColumn("anotherColumn",lit("anotherValue")) \
  .show()
```

Example Source: Google led to https://azurelib.com/withcolumn-usage-in-databricks-with-examples/

Hope it helps...